# How to always launch application from splash screen then last left activity

Tags: java, android, android-activity, task, splash-screen

In my application I have several activities, If I'm leaving application in the middle of the application next time when application relaunches it starts with where I left I want my application to relaunch from splash screen and then it should move to the activity where i left, how can I do that

Comment: Show the Splash screen in Activity onResume

Comment: @Tonteria24 Better to do it in `onStart`, because `onResume` will be called in many occasions.

Comment: onStart is not called on app relaunch if the user leaves the app with Home key.

Answer (score 2):

What exactly you mean be leaving the app?

*Scenario 1*: If user completely removed the app from the recent apps (it was terminated) next time user will open the app `LAUNCHER` (see `AndroidManifest.xml`) will be launched. So you should make your SplashActivity a `LAUNCHER` activity.

*Scenario 2*: In user minimised the app `onPause` and `onStop` and **maybe** `onDestroy` lifecycle methods on the current activity will be called. After user will restore the app from the recents (if the activity was destroyed then first `onCreate` method will be called) then `onStart` and `onResume` lifecycle methods will be called. See more on lifecycle methods in the [docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html).

Showing the splash screen each time user minimises and restores the app from recents not a particularly good idea, so I would recommended to stick with "*Scenario 1*" and show splash screen only once - when user launches the app. But if for some reason you want to show splash screen each time after user restores the app you can check this [tutorial](http://vardhan-justlikethat.blogspot.co.uk/2013/05/android-solution-to-detect-when-android.html). It might be a bit tricky in Android as you can't show it just `onResume` or `onStart` as those methods will be called not only when you restore the app from the recents but also when you start this activity.

Comment: Seems like then in every activity's onResume and onStart i have to launch splash screen manully,

Comment: Also leaving i mean pressing back button and relaunch from app icon or from recent apps

Comment: If you will start splash screen activity in onStart without any additional checks it will be launched even when you start your activity from the code.

Comment: The Splash shown in onResume should be a Dialog and not an Activity, if not it can enter an infinite recursion.

Comment: @blackHawk make `BaseOperationActivity` class which starts splash screen in `onStart`/`onResume` method, and then extend every other activity from this base class, now you are implicitly showing splash screen from these activities just by calling `super.onStart()`/`super.onResume()`